# Подключение библиотеки в CLion [Mac]

Tags: macos, библиотеки, clion

Есть Macbook, CLion в качестве IDE и [библиотека GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/).
Хочется в проекте использовать библиотеку, но не получается подключить. Большинство примеров в гугле для Boost и с GSL они не прокатывают.

**UPD:**
Нашёл [вариант](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqjokCekMM8), но чего-то не хватает:
[image: Содержимое CMakeLists.txt и ошибка]

Содержимое файла `Findgsl.cmake`:

```
set(FIND_gsl_PATHS
        ~/usr/local/)
find_path(gsl_INCLUDE_DIR gsl
          PATH_SUFFIXES include
          PATHS_ ${FIND_gsl_PATHS})

find_library(gsl_LIBRARY
             NAME libgsl
             PATH_SUFFIXES lib
             PATHS ${FIND_gsl_PATHS})
```

Содержимое каталога `/usr/local/`:
[image: Содержимое каталога <code>/usr/local/</code>]

h-файлы лежат в папке `gsl` и имеют имя `gsl_*.h`. 
В исходниках подключение файла из библиотеки выглядит так:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_*.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто прописал руками пути.
Содержимое файла `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(newnewton)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp TVector.cpp TVector.h Tools.cpp Tools.h newton.cpp newton.h gradient_descent.cpp gradient_descent.h functions.cpp functions.h)
add_executable(newnewton ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(gsl_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include)
set(gsl_LIBRARY /usr/local/lib)
find_package(gsl REQUIRED)
include_directories(${gsl_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${gsl_LIBRARY})
```

**UPD:**
Подобный вариант решил проблему, когда IDE не видела хэдеры библиотеки. Однако функции из библиотеки не распознавала.

Путём гугления `clion gsl` нашёл на Stack Overflow ответ и подредактировал своё:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(newnewton)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp TVector.cpp TVector.h Tools.cpp Tools.h newton.cpp newton.h gradient_descent.cpp gradient_descent.h functions.cpp functions.h)
add_executable(newnewton ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(gsl_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include)
find_package(gsl REQUIRED)
include_directories(${gsl_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)
```